# ROS objects introspection in Python

Tags: python, oop, introspection, ros

How can I see attributes and methods of ROS objects ? Can I use inspect module of Python ?

Like in python I can use dir(), type() commands.

Answer (score 0):

I know a couple of hacks for Python modules. Please do the following.

```
import os
print os.getcwd() # to get the current working directory
print os.listdir(os.getcwd()) # to get the contents of the current working directory
```